# MyPy Incompatible default for argument - "Type[str]" vs "Callable[[str], obj]"

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have a function that accepts a Callable as one of its parameters, and returns whatever that Callable returns. So I want to enforce that the return type of my function `do_stuff()` is the same as the return type of its parameter `some_callable`.

MyPy has no complaints about this:

```
CallableResult = TypeVar("CallableResult")


def do_stuff(
    some_text: Text,
    some_callable: Callable[[Text], CallableResult],
) -> CallableResult:
    """Do stuff"""
    return some_callable(some_text)
```

I'd like to also supply a default argument for the Callable parameter `some_callable`, such as 'str':

```
def do_stuff_with_default(
    some_text: Text,
    some_callable: Callable[[Text], CallableResult] = str,
) -> CallableResult:
    """Do stuff"""
    return some_callable(some_text)
```

But then MyPy raises an error on the parameter declaration for `some_callable`:

`error: Incompatible default for argument "some_callable" (default has type "Type[str]", argument has type "Callable[[str], CallableResult]")`

That confuses me, because while `str` IS a `Type`, isn't it also a `Callable`? If so, why does MyPy reject `str` as the parameter default value?

I can silence the error by adding constraints to my `TypeVar()` declaration:

`CallableResult = TypeVar("CallableResult", Any, Text)`

But I'm not sure is this actually enforces my function's return type in the way that I want.

Comment: This is a [known mypy bug](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737), unfortunately: you cannot specify default to generic parameter.

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for the heads up, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Guido Van Rossum pointed out in [this mypy issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3737#issuecomment-316263133) you can use `typing.overload`:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Any, Callable, Text, TypeVar, overload
from typing_extensions import reveal_type


CallableResult = TypeVar("CallableResult")


@overload
def do_stuff_with_default(
    some_text: Text,
    some_callable: Callable[[Text], CallableResult],
) -> CallableResult:
    ...


@overload
def do_stuff_with_default(
    some_text: Text,
) -> str:
    ...


def do_stuff_with_default(
    some_text: Text,
    some_callable: Callable[[Text], CallableResult] | Callable[..., str] = str,
) -> CallableResult | str:
    """Do stuff"""
    return some_callable(some_text)


x = do_stuff_with_default(1)
y = do_stuff_with_default(1, int)

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(x)  # revealed type is str
    reveal_type(y)  # revealed type is int
```

Comment: Thank you for the link to that GH issue thread! It does a fantastic job of explaining the problem, and the evolution of thinking about it... I accepted your answer, even though there are a couple of other workarounds with various tradeoffs, because @overload seems to be the most common best solution. When I get a chance, I would like to come back here and discuss the other approaches.